# How to do a SQL NotLike in nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am creating a conjunction for a Criteria like so:

```
Conjunction conjuction = Restrictions.Conjunction();
conjuction.Add(Restrictions.Eq("RefId", this.project.Id));
conjuction.Add(Restrictions.Like("Type", "%Desired%"));
```

This works. I want to also exclude any rows that contain values with "NotDesired", so I tried this:

```
conjuction.Add(Restrictions.NotLike("Type", "%NotDesired%"));
```

but `NotLike` is not a thing for nHibernate. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should be able to wrap any restriction with **`Restrictions.Not()`**:

```
conjuction.Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Like("Type", "%NotDesired%")));
```